# Missing the "Type" attribute from Amazon SNS message

Tags: email, php, amazon-web-services, https, json

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-subscription-confirmation-json

I read the above guide that is showing the "Type" attribute in the demonstration. However, I can't get that attribute from the message sent from SNS with SES.

Since I am setup the Mautic server to sending email. It needs that attribute to identify the message type for the next action, for example bounced or complaint email.

And my Mautic, it is getting the following error:

```
[2019-07-30 23:19:00] mautic.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: "Key 'Type' not found in payload " at /var/www/mautic/app/bundles/EmailBundle/Swiftmailer/Transport/AmazonTransport.php line 116 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException(code: 0): Key 'Type' not found in payload  at /var/www/mautic/app/bundles/EmailBundle/Swiftmailer/Transport/AmazonTransport.php:116)"} []
```

And I checked source PHP file that is definitely saying the "Type" attribute like the Amazon guide showing. Do any guys know how to setup the Amazon SNS and SES for the "Type" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved!

Don't enable the raw message when you are creating the subscription with HTTP/S.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld3YR.png)